# JavaScript: Count inputfields in a Div

Tags: javascript, html, input, input-field

I have a `<div id="inputform">` and in that `div` there are multiple `<input type="text">` .
How can I count the number of `<input>` fields?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var inputFormDiv = document.getElementById('inputForm');
alert(inputFormDiv.getElementsByTagName('input').length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) you would be able to count the number of elements of a certain type, class, etc. using the following line of JavaScript

```
$("div#inputForm input").length
```

If you're not using jQuery, take a look at [Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23412245/657674), it should do what you need it to.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#inputform input[type="text"]').length;
```

Comment: He did not limit his request to inputs with type text, actually. Otherwise, a fine answer if he's using jquery.

Comment: This requires jQuery. Thom did not state whether or not he is using jQuery.

Comment: You're missing an ending single quote after the selector

Comment: Thanks for the spot, @AndersG, I fixed it for him.